# AngularJS unable to get template from $templateCache

Tags: angularjs, caching, angularjs-ng-template

I am not able to get the template snippets from template cache (which looks like the following:)

```
<script id="sub1.html" type="text/ng-template">
<div> sub1 Content</div></script>
```

I think it is because of line number 11 in index.html file

```
<div class="hiddenContent" ng-include="'templates.html'">
```

If I replace this line with the templates.html it works.

How to make this work keeping the line number 11?

Look at my code in [Plunkr Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/qDRX8jNGq568P3usQWOM)

Comment: I do not think that Angular loads nested templates.

Comment: Yeah I too thought so, that Angular does not load templates from nested template cache. BUT is there any way to confirm this limitation?

Comment: Yes, your plunk confirms it :)

Answer (score 0):

It works, try moving the template into the index.html

http://plnkr.co/edit/MOwCD8UyRT2IBmaeeAMX?p=preview

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.16" data-semver="1.2.16" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="hiddenContent" ng-include="'templates.html'">
  </div>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  {{test}}
  <myapp-directive></myapp-directive>

  </div>
</body>

</html>

<script id="sub1.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <div>sub1 Content</div>
</script>

<script id="sub2.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <div>sub2 Content</div>
</script>
```

Maybe the problem is AngularJS can't find the ng-template in another file. It also work if you define the sub1.html in templateCache:

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.run(["$templateCache", function ($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("sub1.html","<div> sub1 Content</div>");
}]);
```

Comment: I know. I've mentioned this briefly in my question as well. However this is not the way I want to go about because this is just an example and in real project this is pretty big template content that is going to come. Hence I prefer to separate the html template into a different file and then include it as show in line number 11 of the plunkr code. So is there any way to work with it?

Comment: Why don't you just create a sub1.html file and put the <div> inside there? Put many templates inside 1 file isn't a nice solution anyway.
http://plnkr.co/edit/pJ0nK2Rz9X6dGST7Z9PQ?p=preview

Comment: Because the template snippets are huge and can make the code unreadable, I do not want to put it in the same file.